# C# I can not print decimal value in label

Tags: c#, asp.net, label, double

This is my code, setting it on a label does not show me the expected result:

```
DateTime duracionEstandar = Convert.ToDateTime(txtDuracionEst.int 
duracionHoras = 
duracionEstandar.Hour;
int duracionMinutos = duracionEstandar.Minute;
double duracion = duracionMinutos / 60;
lblEstadoEspecialistas.Text = "Horas: " + duracionHoras + ", minutos: " + 
duracionMinutos + " = " + duracion.ToString("0.##");
```

Input:
`txtDuracionEstandar = 1:30`

Result: `Horas: 1, minutos: 30 = 0`

Comment: Read carefully the rules about the [division operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691373(v=vs.71).aspx)

Comment: You're dividing two integer types, `duracionMinutos / 60` is using an integer division, which means the 'decimal portion is dropped'. (Hint: it *never* existed to begin with.) Try using `60.0` instead of `60`, or change `int duracionMinutos` to `double duracionMinutos`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast **int** `duracionMinutos` as a **double**. Write your line of code as such:

`double duracion = (double)duracionMinutos / 60;`